# Redux Toolkit createAsyncThunk question: state updates after async dispatch call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am learning Redux Thunk now. I tried to use `createAsyncThunk` from `Redux Toolkit` to deal with user log in and I encountered some problems. I created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pcizc) here ('right@gmail.com' + whatever password => success, other combination => rejection).

I created a modal for users to input their emails and passwords using `reactstrap`. Click the `Login` button then you will see the form.

Here is my `UserSlice.js` file:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { loginFeedback } from "./feedBack";

export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    "user/login",
    async (userInfo, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await loginFeedback(userInfo);

            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            return rejectWithValue(err);
        }
    }
);

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isLoading: false,
    user: null,
    error: null,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "users",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [login.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = true;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;

        },
        [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.user = action.payload;
        },
        [login.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.user = [];
            state.error = action.payload.message;
        },
    },
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

So in my `LoginModal.js` file, when the Login button is clicked, it will fire up the form submit function `handleSubmit()`:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(login({ email, password }))
        // something else....
}
```

So in `UserSlice.js`, `login` function will take care of the async call to fetch data since I used `createAsyncThunk`. The `createAsyncThunk` will create three actions: `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected`. and I defined the actions accordingly in the `extraReducers` in my `userSlice`.

```
// userSlice.js
        [login.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = true;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;

        },
        [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.user = action.payload;
        },
        [login.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.user = [];
            state.error = action.payload.message;
        },
```

So if the `loginFeedback` succeeded, the `isAuthenticated` state should be set as `true`, and if the call is rejected it will be set as `false` and we will have an error message show up in the form.

In my `LoginModal.js`, I want to close the modal if the user authentication is succeeded, and if fails, then shows the error message. To treat the action like normal promise contents, I found this in Redux Toolkits ([here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)):

> The thunks generated by createAsyncThunk will always return a resolved promise with either the fulfilled action object or rejected action object inside, as appropriate.

> The calling logic may wish to treat these actions as if they were the original promise contents. Redux Toolkit exports an unwrapResult function that can be used to extract the payload of a fulfilled action or to throw either the error or, if available, payload created by rejectWithValue from a rejected action.

So I wrote my `handleSubmit` function as:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(login({ email, password }))
            .then(unwrapResult)
            .then(() => {
                if (isAuthenticated && modal) {
                    setEmail("");
                    setPassword("");
                    toggle();
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setHasError(true);
            });
    };
```

We first `unwrapResult`, then if the promise returns succeeded plus the state `isAuthenticated` and the `modal` are true then we `toggle` (close) the modal, otherwise we log the error.

However, the modal does not close even if I see the `user/login/fulfilled` action executes by the Redux DevTool, and the `isAuthenticated` state is set as `true`.

[image]

In my understanding, the `isAuthenticated` should already set to be `true` when the `login` thunk finishes, so we have everything ready when we call the `.then()` method. Is it because I get the `isAutheticated` state by `useSelector`, so it requires some time to update itself? So we cannot guarantee React Redux already updated it when the promise return? Is there a better way to close the modal when succeeded?

I appreciate your help! You can find the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pcizc). ('right@gmail.com' + whatever password => success, other combination => rejection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the return value from the `Promise` inside the `then` callback does signify that the login operation is successful. But that doesn't mean you will get `isAuthenticated` as `true` because your `handleSubmit` would have been closing over the previous value of `isAuthenticated` which was `false`.

You would require to have a custom `useEffect` which triggers on `isAuthenticated` and other values that your logic requires.

The following changes should satisfy what you need :-

```
  const toggle = useCallback(() => {
    setHasError(false);
    setModal((modal) => !modal);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated && modal) {
      setEmail("");
      setPassword("");
      toggle();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, modal, toggle]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login({ email, password }))
      .then(unwrapResult)
      .catch(() => setHasError(true));
  };
```

Here is the codesandbox :-

[image: Edit react-modal (forked) - stackoverflow]

Comment: Hi @Lakshya Thakur! Can I interpret it this way: `isAuthenticated` and `modal` are side effects that independent of component rendering, so we should put them into `useEffect` hook to make sure React renders them when needed? Thank you!

Comment: Okay let me try and explain this. isAuthenticated and modal are state values which change on every render either by redux or as local state. And each render also creates a new handleSubmit function here. The thing is that you dispatched the Login call from inside a handleSubmit which led to a state update and subsequent render. So its only in the handleSubmit of new render you would have latest isAuthenticated value and not in the old one. The best place to access these values is in a useEffect which takes them in its dependency array and it’s inner callback triggers when they change.

Comment: Wow, I don't know that React generates new functions at each render. Thanks a lot, now I get it.